# How to make a delayed job enqueue itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I am implementing a video streaming interface for Azure's Media Services API in Rails and I need to continuously update the uploaded video in order to process it (copy, encode) through Media Services, the status will eventually be either available or failed. To do this I decided to use delayed jobs, however, I am not sure what's the best way to keep a job always running.

```
class UpdateAzureVideosJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :azure_media_service

  def perform
    to_update = AzureVideo.all.map{ |v| v if v.state != 5 }.compact
    unless to_update.empty?
      to_update.each do |video|
        video.update
      end
    end

    sleep(5)
    Delayed::Job.enqueue self
  end

  def before(job)
    Delayed::Job.where("last_error is NULL AND queue = ? AND created_at <   ?", job.queue, DateTime.now).delete_all
  end
end
```

The reason I delete previous jobs of the same queue is because when I call enqueue method inside perform it adds an extra job which then adds an extra job and the queue with the scheduled jobs gets dirty really quickly.

I am just experimenting and this is probably the closest workaround (although a bit silly) for my case. I haven't tried other alternatives but any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited to something like a `cron` job, or a single daemonised script? If you want the job to re-run indefinitely, it seems a bit pointless to re-enqueue a background task over and over.

Comment: Or alternatively, why not just enqueue a job *when an `AzureVideo` gets `state=5`*, and pass in that id/model as a parameter? Then you don't need to keep polling the entire record set like this.

Comment: Side note 1: Doing `.all.map { ... }.compact` is incredibly inefficient. You should use `.where.not(state: 5)`

Comment: Side note 2: The `to_update.empty?` check is redundant. If the array is empty, then the `.each` will not yield anything anyway.

Comment: Side note 3: The whole point of enums is to map "human-friendly names" to "computer-friendly" numbers. You shouldn't be referencing `state=5` in the code, you should be referencing whatever it's called in the enum. http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html -- What you're doing now *works*, but it misses out on one of the main benefits to this technique.

Comment: I've got to agree. If your job is always running it's not a job, it's a background process. Those aren't hard to write, you'll just need something to stand it back up if it crashes out and there's dozens of tools that "daemonize" things like that, including `systemctl` if that's available for you.

Comment: I wonder if `def after(job); Delayed::Job.enqueue job; end` won’t do?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
def after(job)      
  Delayed::Job.transaction do
    Delayed::Job.create(handler: job.handler, queue: job.queue, run_at: job.run_at + 5.minutes)
    job.destroy
  end
end
```

It will re-schedule the job to run every `5.minutes` after original has finihsed. Been using it in production for major part of the year with out any issues. Also have the same logic in `#error(job)` callback